# Disabling CheckBox in MultiChoiceItems AlertDialog

Tags: android, checkbox, dialog, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I have an `AlertDialog` which it has dynamic items linked to a Cursor from database , it works fine but i wanted to disable user interaction with that because it's an informational dialog , i've disabled my dialog with :

```
alert.getListView().setEnabled(false);
```

but the problem is when Items in the list are bigger than the dialog height , because of disabling it's ListView, Scrolling is disabled too and some items doesn't show up, i've tried some links like : [Android : How to disable CheckBox in AlertDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889728/android-how-to-disable-checkbox-in-alertdialog)
with no success. i've also tried :

```
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(mDBAdapter.instance.getName(SupervisorGuid)
                , SyncDBHelper.instance.SentSupervisors(SupervisorGuid),new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                            if(isChecked==true)
                            {

                                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, true); 
                            }


                    }});
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Does anybody know a better way to disable the checkboxes without a Custom dialog?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this may give you some idea...

```
private void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Boolean> selectedList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        arrayList.add("" + i);
        selectedList.add(i % 2 == 0);
    }
    builder.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(arrayList, selectedList), null);
    builder.show();
}


 public static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> selectedList;

    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList,
            ArrayList<Boolean> selectedList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.selectedList = selectedList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(parent.getContext(), position);
    }

    private RelativeLayout getView(Context context, int position) {
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
        AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 30;
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(textView);
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(context);
        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 30;
        checkBox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        checkBox.setClickable(false);
        if (selectedList != null) {
            checkBox.setChecked(selectedList.get(position));
        }
        relativeLayout.addView(checkBox);
        return relativeLayout;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

...

builder
    .setTitle(...)
    .setMultiChoiceItems(cursor, IS_CHECKED, LABEL, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                ((AlertDialog)dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, /* assign here the original boolean value of the item */);
            }
    })

...

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

In summary, when you click the item in the list, just set its value back to the original boolean value.

Comment: should can we do by default ? without any click? means when we open popup direct it show as clicked?

Answer (score 0):

you can define your check box value with boolean array
"**checkValues**" is our boolean array which defines which check box should tick or which not. check below ex.

> builder.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList, checkedValues)

```
    private fun showDialog() {
    val dialogList: Array<String> = days
    val checkedValues = BooleanArray(days.size)
    checkedValues[viewpager.currentItem] = true
    val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    

    builder.setTitle("You can copy"+dialogList[viewpager.currentItem]+" time slot to:")
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList, checkedValues)
    { dialog, which, isChecked ->
        (dialog as AlertDialog).listView.setItemChecked(yourIndex, true)

    }.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, id ->
      
            dialog.dismiss()
    }.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
            dialog.dismiss()
    }.show()
}
```